# HTTP Client not initiate TCP FIN/ACK when Server sends PSH,FIN,ACK

Tags: http, tcp

I am implementing my own TCP protocol stack and an extremely simple HTTP server on UBoot, and I run into problem that client does not send FIN/ACK after I send FIN/ACK/PSH.  Both HTTP and TCP content seems to be right regarding TCP sequence and Ack, and content length, but client only respond with FIN in its first attempt on any URL.  Any subsequent attempt on the visited URL does not respond with FIN.  Can someone tell me what I am missing in my TCP or HTTP content, that cause the client to not close the connection?

I provided a capture in case anyone is interested in this problem
[Link to packet capture](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1GsvOtRer7klVYL7MiZ8fKcesYa_CyMxV)

The expected result should be client display the content of the HTTP 404 Not found.  However, all I see if browser keeps loading non-stop until the client send a TCP RST, and the browser display Page cannot be found.

Comment: You pcap is full of unrelated packets and it is not clear which part of the pcap are relevant to your problem. Please reduce your pcap to the essential parts and clearly describe in your question which parts of the pcap (i.e. which TCP flows based on number of `tcp.stream` or the involved port numbers) are relevant for which part of the behavior you see.

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  For the filter, just filter IP Address 192.168.99.9 and TCP.  Mainly the request for /ncsi.txt.  Please let me upload another one, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Please let me comment on another thing.  I use chrome's Developer Analyzer, and find that the browser itself didn't actually receive the response.  So chances are the problem still lies in TCP session.  tcp.stream 0 is the first one and the only one that successfully receive FIN/ACK from client.  The subsequent one cannot.  This behavior can apply to other URI as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the streams which issues (like `tcp.stream eq 1` in the pcap) the 404 from the server does not get acknowledged by the client, which likely means that it is dropped somewhere. In the stream without issues (`tcp.stream eq 0`) the 404 gets acknowledged. Looking closer at both 404 reveals that the good one has a valid TCP checksum while the dropped one does not. Thus, most likely your TCP checksum calculation is wrong and the client system is dropping these wrong packets so that they never reach the client application.

Comment: Thank you for your comment.  May I ask are you validating the TCP checksum using the Wireshark TCP validator?

Comment: @TommyLin: correct, I've enabled TCP checksum validation in Wireshark. The data from client all have the wrong checksum which is likely because you've captured at the client side and you are doing TCP checksum offloading, i.e. the TCP checksum gets calculated on the network card after the capture is done. But the TCP checksums from the server should be all correct but some are and others are not - and the ones which are not get dropped on the client side.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is caused by a very strange issue regarding malloc().  When I called malloc(), the buffer contains the previous packets (including the checksum) from the previous malloc(), which will result in incorrect calculation.  However, after setting the content of the TCP header manually, the operation works.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @TommyLin: This is the expected (and well documented) behavior of malloc, i.e. it does not initialize memory which means the memory might contain previous data. If you want to have initialized memory use calloc instead.